# Trouble when deleting emails from Outlook with Python

Tags: python, outlook

When using a generator to iterate through emails in Outlook i am having some trouble deleting them. If i call delete on the message the generator will "jump" over the next item so it will only process half of the emails in my Inbox.

```
for message in scanner.scan_emails():
            message.Delete()
            deleted_counter += 1
```

As a workaround i save all the messages in a list then loop through them:
    for message in emails_to_delete_list:
            message.Delete()

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

For windows you can use win32com (pip install pypiwin32). 6 is you main "Inbox".
  Iterate through the folders and each email and call Delete.

```
import time
import win32com.client


def email_deleter():

    folders = ["BORK", "FOO", "SPAM", "EGGS"]

    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

    for folder in folders:
        emails = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders[folder]
        for email in emails.Items:
            email.Delete()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        email_deleter()
```

Answer (score 0):

[See VB reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/items-folders-and-stores/delete-all-items-and-subfolders-in-the-deleted-items-folder) use backward for loop:

```
items = outlookObject.Items
for i in range(items.Count, 0, -1):
    items.Item(i).Delete()
```